# Array Out Of Bounds Error on Next Bit String Algorithm

Tags: java

This is my code. It runs fine but at the end of the run I get this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at Hwk8_Prob7.NextBitString(Hwk8_Prob7.java:27)
    at Hwk8_Prob7.main(Hwk8_Prob7.java:18)

Any idea why?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Hwk8_Prob7
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int[] bit_string = {0,0,0,0,0};
      final char[] S = {'E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A'};
      ArrayList<Character> subset = new ArrayList<>();
      for( int i = 1; i <= 32; i++)
      {
         System.out.print( Arrays.toString( bit_string ));
         subset.clear();
         for(int j = bit_string.length-1; j >=0; j--)
            if( bit_string[j] == 1 )
               subset.add( S[j] );
         System.out.println("\t" + subset.toString() );
         NextBitString( bit_string );
      }
      System.out.println( Arrays.toString( bit_string ));
   }

   public static void NextBitString( int[] b )
   {
      int i = 0;

      while(b[i] == 1)
      {

         b[i] = 0;
         i++;

      }

      b[i] = 1;

   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong but you have no check to assert that you are within the bounds of the array. So it is possible that the last time b[i] == 0 is also the last element in the array.

Therefor lets say the Array b has 5 values. it goes through all values and finds that all values are equal to 1. by the time it hits the last value it still increments i from 4 (the last location in the array) to 5 (Arrays start at 0 not 1). Then after kicking out of the while loop it tries b[5] but that does not exist thus causing an out of bounds error.

Answer (score 0):

That is because in you could you are not testing looping for a valid range

In you main code, you are doing it correct

```
for(int j = bit_string.length-1; j >=0; j--)
        if( bit_string[j] == 1 )
```

but then in `NextBitString` you are just wildly looping

```
while(b[i] == 1)
{
```

when `i == 5` then you will b exceeding the length of the array

Comment: Yes I tried to limit this by adding

while(b[i] == 1 && i < 4)
      {

but then it doesn't print out all the data at the end

Comment: this expression will be evaluated left to right, so the `b[i]` part will be tested first (some problem).  Try `while(i < 5 && b[i] == 1)`

Comment: I tried that as well but it still throws the Out of Bounds error

Comment: Of course, after your loop, you can not do `b[i] = 1;` because `i` will now be `5`

Comment: Oh duh, just put an if statement around it and it's good now! Thanks for your help!